# How to make cancel build key bindings work

Tags: go, windows-10, sublimetext3, key-bindings

Sublime text 3 cancel build key bindings isn't working

I have tried using this

```
[

{ "keys": ["ctrl+pause"], "command": "exec", "args": {"kill": true} }

]
```

I have tried also with other keys thats unique like ctrl+alt+b but still doesnt work.

I use this with Go, using windows 10 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

The command executed by the built-in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Break</kbd> key combo (**`Tools → Cancel Build`** in the menu) is:

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+break"], "command": "cancel_build" },
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Pause</kbd> should also work, as <kbd>Pause</kbd> is a bindable key according to the [unofficial](https://docs.sublimetext.io/reference/key_bindings.html#bindable-keys) and [official](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/key_bindings.html#bindings) docs.

Comment: It doesnt work, when i press that during for loop it doesnt get interrupted. I'm using golang. Please help me, really need a way to force stop build

Comment: Does using **`Tools → Cancel Build`** work? Also, can you add your build system to your question?